# SXA import doesn't create items for custom styles

Tags: sxa

We are using SXA 1.7.1 to develop a website but we're dealing with this issue that makes development much slower than it should be.

When you export a page using the creative exchange, you would usually add classes in the html on elements that have the "add-classes-here" class. Then when you import, style items are created for those classes and they're added to components automatically.

In our case, this doesn't happen. It says that the import was successful but no style items are created. Has anyone else encountered this problem? Any ideas on why this might happen?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this before, I believe it to be a potential bug in the Creative Exchange import code.

If your developers reformat the `html` files after the export, the import is not able to import the new CSS classes and create the style items.

If you make sure you don't reformat any of the html, add your css class names and then import the html, it should work ok.

Comment: Yup, figured that out right after posting this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can make workaround PowerShell script which can export every html template created for SXA component and can also copy the html and css included in the same. When you use exchange to import it gives only html files which can be and can't be relevant to you.
For creating the PowerShell script you need to take care of selection so that you can choose proper files.